# How to run script with nohup through sshpass

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, nohup, sshpass

I want to pass a local script generated on the fly and it will trigger another script on my remote machine to running some commands for a long period of time. this is the command I have tried:

```
cat <<-TMP >testScript
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /c/Users/Administrator/
    ./remoteScript
TMP

# Execute the remote scripts
sshpass -p **** nohup ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=99999 Administrator@REMOTE_IP 'bash -s' < testScript
```

The remoteScript on remote machine will running for 1h and somehow the ssh drop connection in the middle and I found the process has been killed on the remote as well.

I am wondering why the nohup option is not working? Can someone help to solve the problem?

I also tried to the following but not woking as well:

```
sshpass -p **** ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=99999 Administrator@REMOTE_IP 'nohup bash -s' < testScript
```

Comment: Does this script produce write to its standard output while it runs? Do you want to save the output somewhere? Where do you want to save it (local host or remote host)?

Comment: No it doesn't produce write to its standand output while it runs. I would perfer to save them to local, but the thing is the nohup doesn't seem to working in the above commands